# How would I maintain aspect ratio when using background-repeat: round?

Tags: html, css, debugging

I'm trying to figure out how I can maintain the aspect ratio when checking on portrait mode on mobile when using `background-repeat: round;`.  It fits perfectly on portrait, which's what I want, but it's also kind of smushed.

I've tried so many ways to rectify this but to no avail.  `height: auto;` doesn't work nor does `height: 100%;`.  Also, I need to have a fixed height value inside the `div` so that an image appears.  If I remove the height value inside the `div`, the image disappears.

Anyone know a good way of achieving this?  Is it even possible to fix aspect ratio (not make it look smushed) when using `background-repeat: round;`?

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8Lvfyt7e/13/) for reference.

HTML:

```
<div style="background-image: url(&quot;https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/tA1LUTjBih3StgEumRgpY5flSps=/0x0:1700x960/1400x933/filters:focal(714x344:986x616):no_upscale()/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/57514059/mario.0.jpg&quot;); height: 736px;" class="cpi-wall-detailed-image"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.cpi-wall-detailed-image {
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     background-repeat: round;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: left top;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `background-size: contain;` instead of `background-repeat: round; background-size: cover;`? Also, if it's for anything other than personal use, remember to get permission from Nintendo to use that image.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using round which will, by definition, stretch an image if it has to.